# How to better describe a good-riddance farewell?

Tags: phrase-requests

How would you say, "It was a good-riddance farewell", better?

I am writing of a man leaving a dirty jail cell and is more than happy to be leaving.

Comment: Why don't you like "it was good riddance"? And what has "farewell" to with it it? You don't even wish that on some person (never mind a place) that you didn't like.

Comment: "How would you say it" perhaps belongs on [SE Writing](https://writing.stackexchange.com/). *There was no farewell, not even a look behind me at the grotty cell – my only thought was **good riddance***.

Comment: Could you first transpose 'I am writing of a man leaving a dirty jail cell and is more than happy to be leaving' so that much worked in English? There is pretty-much no chance of being misunderstood but how does that matter?

Comment: "It was not a fond farewell."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem you are having is that "farewell" and "good riddance" are almost contradictory. Although it's lost some of its precise meaning, "fare well" comes from "fare" and "well". When we say "farewell" to someone, we are wishing them well. When we say "good riddance" we are not.

Also, we don't usually use "good riddance" as an adjective, which you are doing here.

So, why not "it was good riddance"?